# unable to determine if a string is currently an integer or not

Tags: php, isnumeric, isinteger

The following funciton drove me nuts. How on earth 100x could be equal to 100 and then 100x is reported as an integer?
For the life of me, I cannot figure it out. 
You can copy and paste the whole thing and see it for yourself.
I'm missing a simple point somewhere here, help me out guys.

```
function blp_int($val) {
    $orgval = $val;
    $num = (int)$val;    
    echo "<li><font color=red>val: ". $val . " is being checked to see if it's an integer or not";
    echo "<li><font color=red>orgval: ". $orgval ;
    echo "<li><font color=red>num: ". $num ;
    if ($orgval==$num) {
        echo "<li><font color=red><b>YES IT IS! the [{$orgval}] is equal to [{$num}]</b>";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (blp_int("100"))
{
    echo "<h1>100 is an integer!</h1>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h1>100 is NOT an integer!</h1>";
}

if (blp_int("100x"))
{
    echo "<h1>100x is an integer!</h1>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h1>100x is NOT an integer!</h1>";
}
```

the above code, when run returns the following;

```
val: 100 is being checked to see if it's an integer or not
orgval: 100
num: 100
YES IT IS. the [100] is equal to [100]
100 is an integer!

val: 100x is being checked to see if it's an integer or not
orgval: 100x
num: 100
YES IT IS. the [100x] is equal to [100]
100x is an integer!
```

I can remedy the situation by adding the following bits

```
    if (!is_numeric($val))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

to the top of the blp_int function right off the bat but,.. I'm still super curious to find out why on earth php thinks 100x=100 are equals.

Comment: `is_int`, `ctype_digit`, `filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)`, the latter can disallow/allow hex & octal ints if you want. If you want to use your code, case to int, but then back to string: `if((string)$orgval==(string)(int)$orgval)`

Comment: Your function use `echo` and `return` , try not writing function this way. what's the output? I mean what you see on the screen when `echo` the variables before the int casting and after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [this example](http://ideone.com/9PoRb), casting `100x` as an integer converts it to `100`. Since you are not using **strict comparison**, `'100x' == 100` is true. PHP removes the `x` from it to make just `100`.

You could use strict comparison (which also compares the types), such that `'100x' === 100` would return false. Using it, any time a string was compared to an integer, it would return false.

---

**As per your edit:** `is_numeric` may not be the most reliable, as it will return true for numbers formatted as a string, such as `'100'`. If you want the number to be an **integer** (and never a string), you could use `is_integer` instead. I'm not quite sure what exactly you're doing, but i thought I'd add this note.

Comment: What's the best way to write a function ( maybe call it "is_this_integer($v)" )  which returns true when $V passed to it *seems* to be an integer to the naked eye? so, not just 1 or -1 but also strings such as '1' or ' 1 ' or '-1 ' or ' -1' will all return true, and needless to say 100x or '100x' will not return as integer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use three equal signs in your IF:

```
if ($orgval===$num) {
```

Otherwise PHP casts the value `100x` to `100` and `100=100`.

[Documentation: Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of check do you want to do? There are a few ways you could go about it:

```
if (preg_match('!^[0-9]+$!', $input))

if (intval($input) == $input)

if (intval($input) === $input)

if ('x'.intval($input) === 'x'.$input)
```

It depends on how closely you want to check if it's an integer. Does it matter if you need to `trim()` it first?

Answer (score 0):

Either cast it to an `int` or try http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php. You also need `===` in your if.